# Promise error for file with 'lots' of lines

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, puppeteer, memory-leak-detector

I'm reading a csv file, every line contains a website url.
I have this function for reading the file:

```
function readCSV(csv){

  var lines=csv.split("\n");

  var result = [];

  var headers=lines[0].split(",");

  // for every line of the file I call check_page function to check the policies (csp and xfo)
  Promise.all(
    lines.map(line => {
      var obj = {};
      var currentline=line.split(",");
      console.log("currentline: "+currentline[1])  
      return check_page("https://www."+currentline[1])
    })
  ).then(() => console.log('it worked')).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

This function calls another function inside to getting the csp and xfo header by http-request.

```
async function check_page(web_page){

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(web_page)
    
    
      
    console.log("MAIN: "+page.mainFrame().url())
    /* I  send for every iframe an http request for retrieve the policies from http header */
    var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;       
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    console.log("FACCIO LA GET: "+page.mainFrame().url())
    req.open('GET', page.mainFrame().url(), false);
    req.send(null)
    var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();       
    var arr = headers.trim().split(/[\r\n]+/);
        // Create a map of header names to values
    var headerMap = {};
    arr.forEach(function (line) {
      var parts = line.split(': ');
      var header = parts.shift();
      var value = parts.join(': ');
      headerMap[header] = value;
    });
        
         

    await browser.close();
  
}
```

My code works if I have a small number of lines: but if I have a file with 100 lines I have this error:

```
(node:1076) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:1076) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGINT listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:1076) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGTERM listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:1076) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 SIGHUP listeners added to [process]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

I think I have to divide the work somehow, but I don't know how.

Comment: is that an error, or just a console warning?

Comment: as in, does the process actually STOP when you see that, or does it keep on going?

Comment: When I execute, it keep on going, it prints all the lines of the file, and I can see that in background all 100 browsers are open and after close, but the http requests don't works correctly

Comment: Does it make sense to start a new browser for *every line*? Seems a bit excessive to me.

Comment: Also you're don't seem to be using the browser for anything. What's the point of launching it at all?

Comment: I'm doing an http request for every page, because I need to get the csp and xfo header from it.

Comment: That was not my question. Why are you launching *a full browser* for every page?

Comment: Because in the beginning I needed it for a single page, I don't know how to change it because it's first time that i used promise...

Comment: Tomalak's solution (don't start a _whole browser for every request_) probably solves your issue. If there had been a real need to do this _(scraping, interacting with the page, on-page javascript)_, use a queue [like this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/queue-promise) — enqueue many tasks, choose how many to execute concurrently, rather than _all at once_ (!) which you are doing now, wait until the queue has ended.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bunch of URLs to check and you want to look at the response headers.

There is no need whatsoever to use `puppeteer` for this, let alone launch a full browser for each of your URLs. This is completely pointless and *incredibly* wasteful. Sending one HTTP request per URL is enough.

Using the [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) module, it's a quite straight-forward task.

```
const request = require('request-promise');

function readCSV(csv) {                               // -> 'a,b,c\na,b,c'
    var lines = csv.split("\n");                      // -> ['a,b,c', 'a,b,c']
    var table = lines.map(line => line.split(","));   // -> [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b' ,'c']]
    var requests = table.map(row => request({         // -> [request, request]
        method: 'GET',
        uri: "https://www." + row[1],
        resolveWithFullResponse: true
    }));

    return Promise.all(requests).then(responses => {  // -> [response, response]
        console.log('it worked');
        responses.forEach(response => {
            var hrds = response.headers;
            // hrds is an object. print it, extract info from it, whatever
            // don't forget to look at the other properties of `response`, as well
        });
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

Think of a better name than `readCSV`, because reading CSV is not what the function does.

Comment: This code works correctly, but if I read a site from csv that is down, it returns error 404 and terminate. How can I handle these types of error in order to read the whole file without finishing?

Comment: @Fra96 Currently there is a single error handler (`.catch()`), which goes off for all requests. As you have seen, this means *any* request that is not successful will stop the output. You want to handle each error individually, so you need to append an error handler directly to each `request()`. Return from that handler the value you want to process later-on. This probably depends on the type of error: For example you might want to return different things for 404 or 500 (server-side errors) than for network level errors (i.e. "host not found", SSL errors).

Comment: You can use Promise.allSettled() so one site failure will not fail other requests

Comment: @Fra96 ...or what aminits says.

Comment: @aminits If I use Promise.allSettled() all request return undefined even if all sites on the file don't return http errors